# Ubuntu 19.10 Slow Startup Time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.10, snap

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on a HDD currently, and the boot process took well over 10 minutes, including a crash when I tried to log in for the first time.

`systemd-analyze` gives the following output:

```
Startup finished in 6.812s (firmware) + 3.507s (loader) + 4.778s (kernel) + 9min 56.777s (userspace) = 10min 11.876s 
graphical.target reached after 5min 47.740s in userspace
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` gives the following output:

```
graphical.target @5min 47.740s
└─multi-user.target @5min 47.740s
  └─snapd.service @9min 15.214s +38.185s
    └─snap-core-8935.mount @7min 54.546s +58ms
      └─dev-loop15.device @7min 54.593s +16ms
```

And `systemd-analyze blame` gives this.

```
    9min 40.453s fstrim.service
    5min 22.837s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     2min 1.888s apt-daily.service
    1min 32.525s apt-daily-upgrade.service
     1min 4.467s man-db.service
         38.185s snapd.service
         18.386s networkd-dispatcher.service
         17.061s ModemManager.service
         16.653s fwupd.service
         16.050s udisks2.service
         12.147s dev-sda4.device
         11.431s accounts-daemon.service
         11.094s logrotate.service
         11.058s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.805s grub-initrd-fallback.service
          8.803s grub-common.service
          8.803s apport.service
          8.501s secureboot-db.service
          8.406s avahi-daemon.service
          8.244s NetworkManager.service
          8.233s thermald.service
          8.220s wpa_supplicant.service
          7.961s systemd-resolved.service
          7.742s systemd-journal-flush.service
          7.541s rsyslog.service
          7.424s switcheroo-control.service
          7.171s nvidia-persistenced.service
          6.956s bluetooth.service
          6.873s pppd-dns.service
          6.848s systemd-logind.service
          6.844s gpu-manager.service
          6.317s user@124.service
          5.392s upower.service
          5.354s bolt.service
          5.056s motd-news.service
          4.222s colord.service
          3.390s dev-loop10.device
          3.328s dev-loop2.device
          3.300s dev-loop4.device
          3.296s dev-loop11.device
          2.631s dev-loop13.device
          2.197s gdm.service
          2.096s dev-loop3.device
          2.066s dev-loop7.device
          2.010s dev-loop1.device
          1.895s dev-loop9.device
          1.856s dev-loop8.device
          1.739s dev-loop0.device
          1.715s dev-loop14.device
          1.625s dev-loop12.device
          1.605s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.529s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.395s polkit.service
          1.245s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.235s systemd-udevd.service
          1.176s apparmor.service
          1.158s dev-loop6.device
          1.035s snapd.seeded.service
           709ms systemd-sysctl.service
```

Currently I'm not sure what to make of it since blame seems to indicate that fstrim is causing most of the issue while critical-chain says snap. Could I get any pointers?

**Update**
Contents of /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=37b3cbf5-f57f-4c85-a85a-ba195612dec3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=087C-B9FE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: What about /etc/fstab ?

Comment: @adasiko I have updated the post with fstab content.